# How to split array in array to json ? Map Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

All code is here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-foormat-wi?file=src/app/app.component.ts

You can see array with 3 object but inside object also you can see array...

I need split all array to be object.

Check code:

```
this.allFilters.push(
  Array.isArray(data.value)
    ? data.value.map((obj: any) => {
        return {
          name: obj.name,
          value: obj.value
        };
      })
    : { name: data.name, value: data.value }
);
```

Html print not important this is only for view json.

Right now my allFilters var is like :

```
[{ "name": "one", "value": 1 }, { "name": "two", "value": 2 }, { "name": "three", "value": 3 }],
{"name": "Second", "value": 15 },
[{ "name": "one", "value": 1 }, { "name": "two", "value": 2 }, { "name": "three", "value": 3 }, { "name": "four", "value": 4 }]
```

Array with inside Array, Object, Array but I need like this:

```
[ 
{ "name": "one", "value": 1 }, { "name": "two", "value": 2 }, { "name": "three", "value": 3 },
{"name": "Second", "value": 15 },
{ "name": "one", "value": 1 }, { "name": "two", "value": 2 }, { "name": "three", "value": 3 }, { "name": "four", "value": 4 }
]
```

I expect array of objects.

No array of mix array and object.

Just object inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `data.value` is an array and even if you do `map` it will give you the same result.

Modify your `recieveMessage(data)` and use `array.concat()` when it is an array.

```
recieveMessage(data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data.value)) {
        this.allFilters = this.allFilters.concat(data.value);
      } else {
        this.allFilters.push({ name: data.name, value: data.value });
      }
}
```

With `ternary` operator,

```
recieveMessage(data) {
     Array.isArray(data.value) ?
            this.allFilters = this.allFilters.concat(data.value)
          :
            this.allFilters.push({ name: data.name, value: data.value });
}
```

Comment: @Khare this is work but is there any better solution without if and else?

Comment: @TysonF is there any restriction why you don't want to use if and else?

Comment: I will try very rarely to use else in my code

Comment: @TysonF updated answer with `ternary` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Just spread the `map()` result

```js
const allFilters = []


const recieveMessage = (data) => {
  if (Array.isArray(data.value)) {
    allFilters.push(...data.value.map(obj => ({ ...obj})))
  } else {
    allFilters.push({ ...data})
  }
}

data.forEach(recieveMessage)

console.log(allFilters)
```

```html
<script>
const data=[{name:"First",value:[{name:"one",value:1},{name:"two",value:2},{name:"three",value:3}]},{name:"Second",value:15},{name:"Third",value:[{name:"one",value:1},{name:"two",value:2},{name:"three",value:3},{name:"four",value:4}]}]; 
</script>
```